# exc_bad_access code=1 error in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

```
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:theImage.CGImage];

    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:6] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];


    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

    returnImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

I am new in Objective C. I dont understand that: "CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];" this line give "exc_bad_access code=1" error. Thanks for help.

Comment: Check if a value is `nil`.

Comment: Run into the same problem ... did you find any solution?

Comment: I'm using the Apple UIImageEffects class now: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Listings/UIImageEffects_UIImageEffects_h.html
works like a charm!